# Why aren't template type parameters inferred as 'const'?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, type-parameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deducing references to const from rvalue arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075093/deducing-references-to-const-from-rvalue-arguments)

If I have

```
template<class T>
void foo(T &) { }
```

and I call it as `foo((const int)5)`, given that the argument is a `const int`, why doesn't the compiler automatically infer `T` to be `const int`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does, if it's given a const type.  Rvalues (prvalues in C++11) with
non-class types, however, are never cv-qualified, even if you try to say
they are: the expression `((const int)5)` has type `int`.  The reasoning
here is that cv-qualifications only apply to objects, and temporaries of
non-class types aren't objects, but pure values; cv-qualifications can't
apply, because there's nothing to be `const` or `volatile`.

If you write:

```
int const i = 42;
foo( i );
```

, your template will instantiate with `T = int const`.  (As you
wrote it, the code shouldn't compile, because the deduced type
is `int`, so the function takes an `int&`, which can't be
initialized with an rvalue.)

Comment: Just to clarify, what exactly is the "non-class type" here that you're talking about? `int` or `int&` or `const int` or `const int&`? (I'm not sure I know the meaning of the term well enough to understand your answer yet.)

Comment: Since we're talking about adding cv-qualifiers to it, the type must be `int`.  In the original code, at least, the type would have been `int const` (after the cast), except that rvalues of non-class type don't have cv-modifiers.  (It's interesting to note that casting to `int const&` should work.)

Comment: Whoa, so `struct Foo { }; foo((const Foo)Foo());` works fine?! I never knew that! +1 it makes absolutely no sense why `int` is any different from an arbitrary `struct` but this seems to be the correct explanation, thanks..

Comment: @Mehrdad History.  It makes no sense, except that in C, rvalues are never cv-qualified, and C++ wants to behave identically (although in this case, I don't see how it could matter).  But whether a class type is const or not affects function overload resolution: which function you call in something like `foo().bar()`, for example.  So cv-qualifiers have to have an impact on class types.  Anyhow, that's the rationale I was given.

Comment: What exactly would the difference between a normal 42 and a const 42 be?

Comment: @FredOverflow The type, since `const` is part of the C++ type system.  (Presumably, _if_ C++ had gone this route, the type of `42` would be `int const`, and there would be no literal with type just `int`.)

Answer (score 8):

The type of an integer literal is `int`, not `const int`, according to C++03 Standard, clause 2.12.1.2.

> The type of an integer literal depends on its form, value, and suffix.
>   If it is decimal and has no suffix, it has the first of these types in
>   which its value can be represented: int, long  int;...

**Update**

Another relevant type deduction rule might be 14.8.2.1.2.

> If P is not a reference type:
>
> [...]
>
> — If A is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of A’s type
>   are ignored for type deduction.
>
> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type
>   are ignored for type deduction.
>
> If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type
>   deduction.

The code provided by OP wouldn't even compile because it's illegal to bind a non-const reference to rvalue.

Comment: Wow, really? I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know... I guess I had a bad example in the question for illustrating my point. I just fixed it in the question. But the problem still persists even when I explicitly cast it to `const int`, so that's not the real issue, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad, which "problem" exactly?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: It's in the title. When I pass a `const` parameter to `foo`, such as in my (fixed) example, why doesn't `T` become inferred as the given `const` type?

Comment: @Mehrdad: If you actually passed a `const` lvalue argument, like `const int i = 42; foo(42);` [it will](http://ideone.com/7WRVh). The problem doesn't lie with `const`-ness, but with lvalue-/rvalueness.

Comment: @Xeo: Uh, then why doesn't it work with r-values?

Comment: @Mehrdad - what makes you think, it's not passed as `const`?

Comment: @KirilKirov: Because it doesn't even compile (see my example).

Comment: @Mehrdad: Because the rules say so. `int&` also doesn't bind to an rvalue of type `int`, so why should `T&` bind to an rvalue of type `T`? That's just the kind of game template argument deduction plays.

Comment: @Xeo: *"why should `T&` bind to an rvalue of type `T`?"*... wait, but `T` doesn't even *exist* yet, so asking "why should `T&` bind to `T`" doesn't even make sense, since it assumes `T` exists as a real type. `T` has to be *inferred* first, so I'm asking why it isn't inferred as `const int`? If it were inferred as `const int`, then `const int&` could very well bind to `const int`, no problem.

Comment: Andrey: Thanks for the reference to the standard. Do you happen to know *why* the standard explicitly ignores `A`'s `const` modifier during type deduction? (Is it meant to protect against some error, or is it too time-consuming for the compiler to figure out, or something else?) I'm assuming the decision wasn't made arbitrarily, given that it's mentioned explicitly, even though it prevents otherwise-seemingly-valid code from compiling.

Comment: Your comments are fine as far as they go, but they don't apply to his example.  He's not instantiating with an integral literal, but with a cast expression.  And only the last point of your second quote applies, since in his case, `P` is a reference type (with no top level const).  The reason his code doesn't compile (or results in `T = int` in one broken compiler) is because the expression `((int const)5)` is an rvalue of a non-class type, and rvalues of non-class type don't have cv-qualifiers (even when you explicitly say that they should).

Comment: @Mehrdad: James Kanze just has given an excellent explanation. The relevant clause in the standard is 3.10/9: `non-class rvalues always have cv-unqualified types`

Comment: @Andrey: Yup, I saw his answer, thanks. :)